# Automate node insertion fetching urls

Tags: 7

I have a type capitolo that has a field *link* (an external URL) and a numeric field. Each capitolo has its own *link*.

When I create a capitolo with number=1 and *link* = `www.example.com/something/1` I would like my site to fetch that url to check if `www.example.com/something/2` exists, and in that case create another capitolo with number = 2, then check `www.example.com/something/3` and if it exists create another capitolo with number = 3 and as link that link etc. This loop should stop when there is no link with that given number.

All this is possible presuming that the links have all the same pattern obviously.

I would like to do so to automate the insertion of the capitolo type, because if, for example, there are 100 links avaliable for that site, a user should add that capitolo manually 100 times.

I would also like the starting url that has to be fetched by the site to be in any form. I mean, it could be `www.example.com/something/1` or even `www.example.com/something/otherstuff/12`
or `idontknow.org/a/b/c/d/e/2/f/5`.

In this last case, the site should insert a capitolo with url `idontknow.org/a/b/c/d/e/2/f/5`, number=5 and look for `idontknow.org/a/b/c/d/e/2/f/6`, `idontknow.org/a/b/c/d/e/2/f/7` etc...

Any ideas on how i could achieve that? I really don't know where to start from.

Comment: capitolo? is that a node type name?

Comment: @AyeshK it's a content type I created, just like basic page or article.